# Uncaught ReferenceError when creating template

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I am getting one error while creating a bootstrap template. I can't figure out what I am doing wrong. When I search for similar issues, it seems to be the scripts are out of order, but I think they are correctly positioned.

THE ERROR:

Uncaught ReferenceError: Popper is not defined at bootstrap.min.js:6

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>TODO supply a title</title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.min.css">
</head>
<body>
  ...
  <script src="js/jquery.js"></script>
  <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You're missing to include the [Popper.js](https://popper.js.org/) library. To quote the [Bootstrap Quick Start Guide](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/getting-started/introduction/): *jQuery must come first, then Popper.js, and then our JavaScript plugins.*.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As ccKep mentioned, you need to include the Popper.js. You can include it using CDN at the end of your files before `bootstrap.min.js`:

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.3/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
```

you can also download the js and load it locally

Comment: Thanks! That was it.